# PIP and SlikSVN under a proxy

Tags: python, svn, proxy, pip

I am trying to checkout a subversion repository using PIP, since I am  under a proxy I am calling PIP using the --proxy parameter:

```
pip install svn+http://django-compress.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ --proxy=myproxy:8080
```

While PIP itself works fine under the proxy, it seen that its not passing the proxy parameter to the SVN client:

```
Downloading/unpacking svn+http://django-compress.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
  Checking out http://django-compress.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ to c:\users\canassa\appdata\local\temp\pip-x_w9ct-build
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://django-compress.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': could not connect to server (http://django-compress.googlecode.com)
  Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe" checkout -q http://django-compress.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ c:\users\canassa\appdata\local\temp\pip-x_w9ct-build:

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe" checkout -q http://django-compress.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ c:\users\canassa\appdata\local\temp\pip-x_w9ct-build failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in C:\Users\canassa\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

To make things worst I am under a Windows environment and using the SilkSVN client. I also have to switch off the proxy a few times every day since its a notebook and I have to connect it with the wireless, which don't uses a proxy.

My question is if there is a way to handle the SlikSvn proxy under PIP and Windows. Preferably making easy to switch it off when I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an open bug[1] and there is not solution to this problem right now.

If you find an answer, please, comment in pip's issue tracker.

[1] - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/227

Comment: Thanks! I will follow that issue